# How to force Rails to use gem of version X

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app with the config/environment.rb line

```
config.gem 'authlogic', :version => '2.1.2'
```

The system gem for authlogic is 2.1.4
The one in my GEM_PATH is 2.1.2

No matter what I try, Rails is only using the 2.1.4 version, which is a problem. How to force rails to use 2.1.2?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you defined GEM_PATH? If not already there, try push it out as far as into .bashrc (or whatever shell you use).

Comment: See also: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/8082d48596cbe885

Comment: GEM_PATH is set in the terminal I am using. Exported in .bash_profile and set in config/environment.rb too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've made a test here, included the gem authlogic, choose to use the 2.1.3 version, and the application ran without problems.

then i've uninstalled the gem (gem uninstall authlogic -v=2.1.3), and my application didn't ran anymore, normal behavior (i'm using rails 2.3.8 for this test)

you could try uninstalling and then installing the gem again

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/rails23.html)

Answer (score 0):

To be safe, uninstall your 2.1.4 version, freeze 2.1.2, then uninstall 2.1.2 too.

Answer (score 0):

Unpack the gems into your rails app.  This'll also help in deployment.

```
rake gems:unpack
```

Answer (score 0):

Sys admin re-installed some gems and all the problems went away.